# Java Generics Factory SuppressWarnings

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, suppress-warnings

I have a Factory that makes an List. I have three Create methods. The first create method makes a list with Objects. It get the Information from the other two Create methods while the second get the Class from the type T and passes the class type to the third create method which create a new instance and return it.

That's my Factory

```
 public class Factory {

        public <T extends IPrototype<T>> List<T> create(T prototype, int n) throws Exception {
            ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) 
                list.add(create(prototype));
        return list ;
        }

        public <T extends IPrototype<T>> T create(T prototype) throws Exception {
            return (T) create(prototype.getClass());
        }

        public <T extends IPrototype<T>> T create(Class<T> type) throws Exception {
            T obj =  (T) type.newInstance();
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

That's my IPrototype Interface

```
public interface IPrototype<T extends IPrototype<T>> {

}
```

The List can Only have object which implements IPrototype

```
public class Bar implements IPrototype<Bar>{

    public Bar() {}
}
```

My Question is i get a Warning in the second create method.

```
    public <T extends IPrototype<T>> T create(T prototype) throws Exception {
                return (T) create(prototype.getClass());
            }
/*Or method in long way */

    public <T extends IPrototype<T>> T create(T prototype) throws Exception {
        Class<T> cl = (Class<T>) prototype.getClass();
        return  (T) create(cl);
    }
```

> Type safety: Unchecked invocation create(Class) of the generic method create(Class) of type Factory

How i can handle this Warnings ?

That's the Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Factory factory = new Factory();

        Foo prototype1 = new Foo();
        Bar prototype2 = new Bar();

        Foo inst = (Foo) factory.create(prototype1); // one Foo instance
        List list = factory.create(prototype2,10); // ten Bars in List
        List list2 = factory.create(prototype1, 10);


        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(list2);


    }
}
```

Comment: Why use this prototype thing instead of just providing a `Supplier<T>`?

Comment: Honestly: the whole approach to having "prototype objects" is not going to be type-safe.  Use a `Supplier` or the constructor directly; don't try to make this reflective.